# I couldnt use the library that I have already imported as references in my project

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, sift

I am writing a program for computer vision in c# that part of project SIFT is needed; I downloaded the MEMO library for SIFT :

http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/tu-berlin-2006/libsift/

In my project I added the two libraries ****libsift.dll & ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll** ** as references in to my projects.

[image]

Now that I want to mention libsift on top of the code " USING libsift" it doesnt recognize it;

[image]

even more if I wanna make a instance of such class atuo detect doesn't recognize it.

[image]

It is weird because I could see the functions of this library in object browser.

[image]

I couldnt use the library that I have already imported as references in my project although I could see the functions in object browser? What could be the problem?

(I have c# .Net VS2010 in windows.)

Comment: Can you verify whether .net versions are compatible?

Comment: How could I check the version verification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *looks* like they're in the root namespace - not in a namespace called `libsift`. If that is the case, you don't need a `using libsift;` directive - just try accessing `Keypoint` etc directly. Or possibly `global::Keypoint`. It should be noted that dumping types into the root namespace is frowned upon - it makes it hard to avoid conflicts. But that is the fault of `libsift`.

The other possibility is that you've changed the "Aliases" property on the reference; that should be "global". You can see this in the property panel when you select an individual reference in the solution explorer - alongside things like "Copy Local", "Specific Version", etc. If it is anything else: change it back to "global", or learn about *extern aliases*.

Tested locally (the types are in the global namespace):

[image]

Comment: btw, I downloaded it and confirmed: they are indeed in the root namespace

Comment: I did  try accessing "keypoint" directly [ as shown in pic above] but it didnt work.

Aliases: I didnt change anything. Alises= Global; Copy Local=True; Specific version= False.

Regarding root nameSpace/ nameSpace: how should I find out which category siftlib belongs to?

Comment: @farzin "Global"? Or "global"?

Comment: @farzinparsa I've just checked it locally - it works fine; adding screenshot

Comment: @ marc Gravell: I didnt get completely throughly what exactly you meant by saying locally. 
but If I got you right, I shouldnt use the word " libsift" ? I have to go straight using the commands.

Comment: @farzin correct: because they're in the root namespace you don't need yo qualify them. Not ideal, though.